# How to not transpile class/function decorators, preserve them in the output ()

Tags: typescript, tsc

Say I have the following class `Greeter` in `greeter.ts`:

```js
function fooDecorator(constructor: Function) {
  Object.seal(constructor);
}

function barDecorator(value: boolean) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    descriptor.enumerable = value;
  };
}

@fooDecorator
class Foo {
  greeting: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
  @barDecorator(false)
  greet() {
    return 'Hello, ' + this.greeting;
  }
}
```

I get the following `greeter.js` output using `tsc greeter.ts --target ESNext`:

```js
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
function clsDecorator(constructor) {
  Object.seal(constructor);
}
function funDecorator(value) {
  return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    descriptor.enumerable = value;
  };
}
let Greeter = class Greeter {
  constructor(message) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
  greet() {
    return 'Hello, ' + this.greeting;
  }
};
__decorate([
  funDecorator(false)
], Greeter.prototype, "greet", null);
Greeter = __decorate([
  clsDecorator
], Greeter);
```

which is fine if i want to use it directly.

But how to keep class and function decorators in the output and not introduce `__decorate` code?

The desired `greeter.js` output is:

```js
function clsDecorator(constructor) {
  Object.seal(constructor);
}

function funDecorator(value) {
  return function(targe, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    descriptor.enumerable = value;
  };
}

@clsDecorator
class Greeter {
  greeting;
  constructor(message) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
  @funDecorator(false)
  greet() {
    return 'Hello, ' + this.greeting;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way, but why do you want to do this ? What is the usecase ? Maybe we can suggest an alternative

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, the desired output can be consumed by babel transpiler. This way I can switch my typescript code to ESNext typescript anytime, say if the team decided to stick to standard javascript only. With all the advantages that come with typescript, still some developers prefer pure javascript only. I want to have both options available and not dictate typescript. Yes there will be one problem: .ts to .js is one way traffic, but we are ok with this.